# Downloading file retrieved from MongoDB using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm building web application for uploading and downloading files to and from MongoDb using Flask. First I'll search MongoDb database in particular collection for matching string and if there is a matching string in any document, then I need to create dynamic URL(clickable from search page) to download using the ObjectId. Once I click the dynamic URL, it should retrieve file stored in MongoDb for that particular ObjectId and download it. I tried changing `response.headers['Content-Type']` and `response.headers["Content-Dispostion"]` to original values, but for some reason the download is not working as expected.

***route.py***

```
@app.route('/download/<fileId>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def download(fileId):
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient()

    #get a handle to the test database
    db = connection.test
    uploads = db.uploads

    try:
        query = {'_id': ObjectId(fileId)}
        cursor = uploads.find(query)

        for doc in cursor:
            fileName = doc['fileName']
            response = make_response(doc['binFile'])
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = doc['fileType']
            response.headers['Content-Dispostion'] = "attachment; filename="+fileName
            print response.headers

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('Unsuccessful.html')
```

What should I do so that I can download file(retrieved from MongoDB-working as expected) with same file name and data as I uploaded earlier?

Below is the log from recent run.

[image]

The file(in this case "Big Data Workflows presentation 1.pptx") retrieved from MongoDb is downloading with ObjectId file name even though I'm changing file name to original file name.

[image]

Please let me know if I'm missing any detail. I'll update the post accordingly.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try to help in understanding rather than just clicking downvote without commenting the reason. I tried giving as much information regarding the issue as possible.

Comment: Try wrapping filename in "":
response.headers['Content-Dispostion'] = "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" % fileName

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried wrapping filename but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Bartek Jablonski for your input.

Finally I made this work with tweaking code a little bit and creating new collection in MongoDB (I got lucky this time, I guess).

```
@app.route('/download/<fileId>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def download(fileId):
    connection = pymongo.MongoClient()

    #get a handle to the nrdc database
    db = connection.nrdc
    uploads = db.uploads

    try:
        query = {'_id': ObjectId(fileId)}
        cursor = uploads.find(query)

        for doc in cursor:
            fileName = doc['fileName']
            response = make_response(doc['binFile'])
            response.headers['Content-Type'] = doc['fileType']
            response.headers["Content-Dispostion"] = "attachment; filename=\"%s\"" %fileName
        return response
    except Exception as e:
#          self.errorList.append("No results found." + type(e))
        return False
```